# A puzzle about column vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

how to understand the $A_{1\times m}$'s column space?
I already know how to imagine the column space with $A_{2\times m}$ or $A_{n\times m}$, is there a visual description to explain the above problem?

thanks a lot!

Comment: If every entry in $A$ is $0$ then the column space is just $\{0\}$. However, is at least one entry of $A$ is non$-$zero, then its column space is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MatthewH. I get it. I can imagine this just an axis on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The column space is $\mathbf{R}$ because the column vectors are just a $m$ numbers in $\mathbf{R}$. As been said above, if of them are $0$, they don't span $\mathbf{R}$.